# App not working when put inside a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am creating a phone simulator, and and I want to add a few apps to it which are packed in a function. And it is showing errors: `NameError: Name caps_lock is not defined` . I don't know the cause of this error, becase name caps_lock is clearly defined. This error, however is working when executed individually.

Full error traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/MyProjects/application.py", line 109, in <lambda>
    cmd = lambda x=button: buttonClick(x)
  File "/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/MyProjects/application.py", line 96, in buttonClick
    user_input = user_input.upper() if caps_lock else user_input.lower()
NameError: name 'caps_lock' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Module: apps.py; Contains only an app now.

```
from tkinter import *

def on_screen_keyboard():
    root = Toplevel()
    root.geometry("366x650")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.title("On screen Keyboard")

    txt = Text(root, width=44, height=30, wrap=WORD, font='Arial')
    txt.place(x=3, y=50)
    txt.focus_set()

    Label(root, text='', height=32).grid(row=1, column=20)

    buttons = [
        '~', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '←',
        '"', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', '[', ']',
        '⬆️', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/', '?',
        '!', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ':',
    ]

    varRow = 6
    varCol = 0

    caps_lock = False
    letter_buttons = []

    def is_letter(s):
        return len(s) == 1 and 'a' <= s <= 'z'

    def buttonClick(user_input):
        global caps_lock

        if user_input == '⬆️':
            caps_lock = not caps_lock
            for btn in letter_buttons:
                text = btn['text']
                btn['text'] = text.upper() if caps_lock else text.lower()
        else:
            if user_input == ' Space ':
                txt.insert(INSERT, ' ')
            elif user_input == '←':
                backspace()
            elif user_input == ' Return ':
                txt.insert(INSERT, '\n')
            else:
                if is_letter(user_input):
                    user_input = user_input.upper() if caps_lock else user_input.lower()
                txt.insert(INSERT, user_input)

    def backspace():
        txt.delete('insert-1chars', INSERT)

    space_btn = Button(root, width=20, text=' Space ', command=lambda: buttonClick(' Space '))
    space_btn.place(x=50, y=620)

    return_btn = Button(root, width=6, text=' ⏎ ', command=lambda: buttonClick(' Return '))
    return_btn.place(x=250, y=620)

    for button in buttons:
        cmd = lambda x=button: buttonClick(x)

        if button != ' Space ':
            btn = Button(root, text=button, width=3,
                         command=cmd)
            btn.grid(row=varRow, column=varCol)
            if is_letter(button):
                letter_buttons.append(btn)

        if button == ' Space ':
            Button(root, text=button, command=cmd).grid(row=6, columnspan=16)
        varCol += 1

        if varCol > 11 and varRow >= 4:
            varCol = 0
            varRow += 1

    root.mainloop()
```

Second module: Main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from apps import weather_app

app = Tk()
app.geometry("366x650")
app.resizable(0, 0)

canvas = Canvas(app)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)


app1 = Button(canvas, text='App 1', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2, command=weather_app)
app1.place(x=50, y=300)

app2 = Button(canvas, text='App 2', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2)
app2.place(x=150, y=300)

app3 = Button(canvas, text='App 3', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2)
app3.place(x=250, y=300)

app4 = Button(canvas, text='App 4', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2)
app4.place(x=50, y=400)

app5 = Button(canvas, text='App 5', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2)
app5.place(x=150, y=400)

app6 = Button(canvas, text='App 6', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2)
app6.place(x=250, y=400)

app7 = Button(canvas, text='App 7', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2)
app7.place(x=50, y=500)

app8 = Button(canvas, text='App 8', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2)
app8.place(x=150, y=500)

app9 = Button(canvas, text='App 9', highlightbackground='grey', activeforeground='white', fg='black', width=7,
              height=2)
app9.place(x=250, y=500)

app.mainloop()
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please show the full error traceback?

Comment: Also try adding `global caps_lock` to the start of the `on_screen_keyboard` function. Btw it isn't good practise to define functions inside other functions

Comment: `caps_lock` isn't a global variable, it's local to the `on_screen_keyboard` function. Use `nonlocal caps_lock` to access it from nested functions.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks, it's working!